# PIC Programmer Writes To EEPROM

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I am programming a software which I am developing at the moment, to the PIC18f46K80 by TNM 2000 universal programming. When I read back the PIC, I see that the EEPROM has been written some data. This data is which my software writes to the EEPROM under some conditions. I want the EEPROM to be completely clear when I first program the mcu. I have never seen or realized that a programmer to write to eeprom while loading the software to the pic. Do you have any ideas about why this happen?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: I only wonder when I program the microcontroller, shouldnt the eeprom be clear? I am erasing the mcu before programming, and when I erase it, I check the EEPROM, and it is clear. After I program, I read again, the eeprom is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MPLAB X for PIC programming, there should be a "Preserve EEPROM Memory" checkbox in your PICkit configuration.

Make sure its not ticked.

Additionally, you may select the "EEPROM" checkbox to make sure the EEPROM gets erased.

Comment: I am using TNM Universal Programmer. I have sent mail to them, and waiting.